# Can one object call another's functions

Tags: java

I want to set up 2 classes:
`Customer`,
`Transaction`

I want to be able to log in as a customer and then get all their transactions for instance:

```
Customer c1;
Transaction t1;
```

can i call:

```
c1.t1.getTransaction(4);
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the functions have the proper access (e.g., public), you can do that with no problem. You can read about access in the [Java Language Specification, § 6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

Answer (score 1):

Um, no.

If an object has a reference to another, it can call whatever public methods are exposed.   But none of your example code makes any sense.

The example you wrote can only work if you write it this way (not recommended):

```
public class Transaction {
    public void getTransaction(int x) { 
        // I have no idea what you want this to do.
    }
}


public class Customer {
    public Transaction t1;  // Not recommended.
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer();
ct.t1.getTransaction(4);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what i'm trying to do is have several instances of a customer class. Then when the user logs in as one of those customers that instance of the customer object can then call the transactions that are belong to them. sorry if i'm not explaining myself well

Comment: Objects should not know or care about whether or not they are participating in a transaction.  That means "database" to me.  Do you mean you want to get all the invoices or orders for a particular customer?  That's something different.